# "DB" data directive explaination

Tags: programming, microprocessor, assembly, 8051

What exactly is initialization of code memory IN 8051?  Does the db directive command DB "SAM'' burn data into ROM location?

WHAT DOES INITIALIZING WITH A BYTE VALUE MEAN ?

I am all confused?

I am programming assembly in 8051!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about software, not electronic design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it literally puts those bytes into memory. There is no difference between bytes from code and bytes from data, both look exactly the same. The only difference is in how you use them.

Comment: Another thing, can ORG directive be used only for the addresses of code memory,or can i use them for adresses of other memories too?

Comment: It's used for memory. What you put in there is your concern.

Comment: How can i move a bit directly from psw.6 to 5th bit of 20h(05) bit addressable memory location in 8051?

Comment: NFI, I don't do 8051.